# Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s) error mysql on 5.7

Tags: mysql

i am trying to do this consult, and I have the follow error: "Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ev.id) as event_counter,
  events.*
FROM
  `events` INNER JOIN `events_organizations` ON `events`.`id` = `events_organizations`.`event_id`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN events ev ON ev.model_id = events.id 
WHERE
  `events_organizations`.`organization_id` = 1
  AND (events.kind = 1
       AND events_organizations.event_administrator = true)
  AND (events.situation = 1)
  AND (events.event_type_id = '3','5','2','1','4') 
GROUP BY
  events.id
ORDER BY
  event_counter DESC, name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct this:

```
AND (events.event_type_id = '3','5','2','1','4')
```

to this:

```
AND (events.event_type_id IN ('3','5','2','1','4'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM events INNER JOIN `events_organizations`...LEFT OUTER JOIN events
```

See the problem?Same table twice.Remove this line

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN events ev ON ev.model_id = events.id
```

And change the INNER to a LEFT JOIN if you want all events.

Comment: that was syntactically correct though - apparently not a cause for error